# JavaScript - an array in if statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I really need some help with this one, I've been struggling a lot trying to crack the example down on my own for way too long.. the whole issue is that I have an array that includes 15 pictures added by push property & createImage function, the problem though is that I've absolutely no idea how I could use the image in an if-statement like so:

if (check both if the image displayed is the first image within the array and answer equals 'x') return that's a good answer
that's a good answer } else (in case if either the image isn't the first one or answer doesn't equal 'x' return that's not a good answer

So far I've achieved the following, unfortunately enough the program omits the rule regarding the array

```
var answer = document.getElementById("answer");
var image = newArray[0];

    function check() {
        if (newArray[0] == true && answer.value == "C") {
            window.alert("that's a good answer");
        } else if (newArray[0] == true && answer.value == "c") {
            window.alert("that's a good answer as well");
        } else {
            window.alert("that's unfortunately not a good answer");
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any form of help

Comment: How do you know which image is displayed and which is not?

Comment: I've got another function chosing the image out of array randomly attached to a button calling that function.

Answer (score 0):

I obviously had to change things a bit since you don't give us the document or `newArray`, but after adding some dummy data and running it, it works. Can you be more specific about the error(s) you're running into?

Here's my solution:

```js
var answer = "C";
var newArray = [true, false, false, true];
var image = newArray[0];

    function check() {
        if (image === true && answer == "C") {
            window.alert("that's a good answer");
        } else if (image === true && answer == "c") {
            window.alert("that's a good answer as well");
        } else {
            window.alert("that's unfortunately not a good answer");
        }
    }
    
check();
```

Comment: Let me test that, but sure you're right, I should've provided the entire code in the first place shouldn't I, silly me.

Comment: @KarlFriedrich The more code you can provide the first time around, the easier it will be for others to replicate your issue and help you solve it :)